# gradle - custom build.gradle AND settings.gradle

Tags: gradle

folks,

is anyone aware how to use gradle to run with a custom `build.gradle` AND `settings.gradle` - i.e both together?

I think that I can have a custom build.gradle file (`-b` flag) - but then this ignores the custom settings flag `-c` flag.

I think (although I can't immediatley point to thepart in the documentation) that if you specificy a custom build.gradle, then it ignores your settings.gradle override `-c` option.

If this isn't possible - is it possible to inform gradle of a multiproject build using only a build.gradle file and ignoring any `settings.gradle`

motivation is to create a 'lite' version of a fairly large and complex build that only runs certain elements.

Answer (score 0):

The general philosophy of Gradle is to express all different usages in a single build model. That said, here are a few thoughts:

`-b` forces a single-project build using the given build script. I'd say that this feature is mainly intended for demonstration purposes, and I haven't used it for production builds.

In a multi-project build, the location of build scripts is solely determined by the settings script. By default, Gradle will look for a settings script named `settings.gradle`. However, you could have multiple settings scripts and choose among them with the `-c` option, or have multiple `settings.gradle` in different directories and choose among them by starting the build from the appropriate directory. As a last resort, you could write a settings script that conditionally includes different projects, or points to different build scripts, depending on some condition. Note that even single-project builds can have a settings script.

To explore the API available to settings scripts, look up the `Settings` type in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html).